# Fail Gradle build when JUnit test is marked ignored

Tags: java, junit

I have a Java project in which I'm running [`gradle test`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html).
 I would like execution of this task to *fail* if any test is ignored using the [`@Ignore` annotation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html).

I can currently *see* when tests are ignored using the following `test` task configuration in my `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
  testLogging {
    events = ["passed", "failed", "skipped"]
  }
}
```

With this configuration, an ignored test results in a log statement like:

```
TestClass > testName SKIPPED
```

rather than:

```
TestClass > testName PASSED
```

or

```
TestClass > testName FAILED
```

How can I achieve my goal of actually causing execution of this task to fail?

Comment: why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Common example: implementing a team-wide policy of updating or deleting rather than ignoring tests (kind of like deleting or updating code rather than leaving dead, commented-out code lying around). However, in my particular case, I'm contributing to an open source project that manually strips `@Ignore` annotations from a test class. I want to verify that stripping worked correctly by failing the test run if any tests remain ignored after stripping was attempted.

Comment: wouldn't consider it common, but thanks for the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested this yet but this might work:

```
test {
    afterTest { descriptor, result ->
        if (result.resultType == TestResult.ResultType.SKIPPED) {
            throw new GradleException("Do not ignore test cases")
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- [`Test.afterTest`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterTest(groovy.lang.Closure))
- [`TestResult.ResultType`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestResult.ResultType.html)